# Reconciling map/edition differences in Chult & filling in "broad strokes" areas in Tomb of Annihilation? Mezro?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, tomb-of-annihilation

I'm two sessions into DMing Tomb of Annihilation for my face-to-face group and we're really enjoying it. However, I am reading lots of "area descriptions" that are described in exceedingly broad strokes... In an attempt to fill these in I've turned to older edition treatment of Chult (e.g. James Lowder's *Ring of Winter*, AD&D *Jungles of Chult*, 3e *Serpent Kingdoms*) & to DM's Guild products like [Ruins of Mezro](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/220852/Ruins-of-Mezro).

One example, the one that's most immediate for me as my group is headed for Mezro...

Mezro - or its ruins - seems like a really important area. You need to buy a DM's Guild Adept product for a more-than-paragraph description. OK, I got that, but then it paints area descriptions in really broad strokes that are very similar to the (necessarily) broad coverage back in AD&D *Jungles of Chult*. For example, the College of Wizards & Temple of Ubtao are key areas with clues to discover...and are complex shifting/teleporting dungeons yet lack sufficient detail to DM (without making up a dungeon of my own). Has anyone detailed these (or other) areas of Mezro in greater detail?

Thanks for any help you can offer. :) I'm a veteran DM realizing that ToA requires a lot of customization & filling-in-the-blanks, and while I am doing that, I want to make sure I don't overlook things, make glaring mistakes by improvising in a way that invalidates some hidden (but critical) plot point sentence, or recreate the wheel.

Comment: Bravo, you have some great stuff here and I am excited to hear some helpful answers. May I suggest you break this up into several different questions? Your asks are a bit broad in nature.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions, having recently been through these areas (and still running this campaign actively). The issue you mentioned is one I hit as well while running the campaign - areas with very little description that could use more detail. Here was how I handled this during my campaign...

### Alternatives

1. Depending on situation, you might consider more "generic" or non-descriptive details when dealing with repetitive areas (such as shifting mazes or similar encounters). A single statement such as *"This room looks similar, however you have the sense that small details have changed such as the foliage pattern on the wall."*
2. Have a set of descriptions at the ready. Things like entering a generic room suddenly becomes a lot more interesting if you have a description for a random room ready. It does not have to be fancy - just something you can be consistent with. I usually came up with 10-20 descriptive rooms and would pick them randomly.

### Recommended

1. Roll20 has a pre-built campaign already written. Having read through the book first, Roll20 added a lot more detail and information. Though access to this campaign costs money.

Comment: @Quickleaf I am not sure if this 100% answers your question, as I would have to do a lot of additional reading to find out if the content covered by Roll20 is just additional information from WotC or from previous or other sources. That being said, there is a few YouTube video series using Roll20 ToA that you can quickly look at to find out if it has the content you are looking for.